# Adding a facebook "share" link to an email blast

Tags: facebook, email

I have an email blast that includes some facebook and twitter share links. For twitter, I'm using something like:

```
http://twitter.com/?status=Check%20out%20mysite.com
```

As far as I know, this is the recommended way to link to twitter status updates. Facebook used to have the share.php feature which as far as I know, still works, but has been deprecated in favor of the "like" button, which can't really be embedded in an email (lack of javascript / iframe support in most clients).

What is the new recommended way to link to a facebook "share" page? Is there no alternative? If I must continue to use share.php, is there anywhere I can find documentation on the parameters for it since Facebook refuses to preserve old documentation for legacy support?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here you go :

Put a share button in your email with this link :

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.google.com
```

This is the [output](http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.google.com)  you will get

Comment: sharer.php is no longer documented by Facebook and was deprecated, however according to this article http://www.joshuawinn.com/facebooks-sharer-php-longer-deprecated-2014/ the deprecation may now be deprecated. I LOVE programming for Facebook!

Comment: I don't think this is the best solution since clicking the "Post to Facebook" link will try to close a dialogue and you will be left with a blank page. The post will be published to your timeline, but you will have to navigate there to see it.